# What's the easiest in a shell script to ensure its not run as root?

Tags: java, security, shell

I have a Java application executed from a ([ba]sh) shell script and unfortunately sometimes the people responsible for deploying it and starting it fail to switch to the appropriate user before starting the application.  In this situation I'd like the application to not run at the very least, and ideally issue a warning not to do that.  I thought about trying to alias java or change the path for root to include a fake java which does so, but this might have undesirable side effects and isn't going to be effective easily since the shell script specifies the full path to the java binary.

So, is there a standard idiom in shell scripts for 'don't run if I'm root'?

Comment: Please indicate the shell... BASH shell, CMD shell?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think of CMD shell scripts as shell scripts so much as 'batch files', so it didn't occur to me to differentiate.

Comment: bash has `$EUID` but cristis has the portable answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example in bash:

```
if [ `id -u` = 0 ]; then
  echo "You are root, go away!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In BASH, you can take the output of [`whoami`](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/whoami.1.php) and compare it to `root`.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this at the beginning of scripts that I want to
be run under a service account:

```
LUSER='my-service'
if [ `id -un` != $LUSER ]; then
    exec su  $LUSER -s $SHELL -c "$0 $@"
fi

# actual script commands here.
```

If run as the correct user, execution will continue as planned. If run
as root, privileges are dropped to the wanted user-id. Other users
will get a password prompt which should tell them that something is
wrong.

`su -s $SHELL ...` is used to override the shell set in `/etc/passwrd`
-- it may be set to `/bin/false` for the service account.

I have used this on Debian systems, using `bash` and `dash`. Feel free
to comment if portability can be improved.

Comment: well, I think there isn't a specific user that will be deploying and running the java app... it's important just that it's not root.

Comment: id -u gives a number rather than a name.  You probably meant id -un.